# Удаление элементов с DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Хочу написать функцию которая удалила б из двух колонок все childElememntsы после их добавления в divы, но удаляется только одна.

```
function myFunction() {
   let element = document.getElementById('name_out');
   while (element.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="square">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inputs">
                    <h2>Enter: Name = Value</h2>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                    <input id='xArray' class="inp_t">
                    <button id='button' class="inp_t">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                    <p><button id='button' class="inp_t" onclick="sortByName()">Sort by Name</button></p>
                    <p><button id='button' class="inp_t" onclick="sortByValue()">Sort by Value</button></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- <div class="buttons">
                    <ul id="navp">
                        
                        </ul>
                        
                </div> -->
                 
            </div>

            <div class="textcols">
                <div class="textcols-item">
                    <h2>Name:</h2>
                    <div id="name_out"></div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="textcols-item">
                    <h2>Value:</h2>
                    <div id="outd"></div>
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id='button' onclick='myFunction()' >Delete</button> 
        </div>
       
    </div>

<script src="action1.js"></script>    
</body>
```

JS

```
let inputValX,
    button = document.getElementById('button'),
    xArr = [];

const innerName = document.getElementById('name_out');
const innerValue = document.getElementById('outd');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputValX = document.getElementById('xArray').value;
    xArr.push([inputValX.split('=')].reduce((acc, [name, value]) => {
      acc.name = name;
      acc.value = value;
      return acc;
    }, {}));
    name_out();
});

function name_out() {   
     let name_out = '';
     let outd = '';

   xArr.forEach((item) => {
         name_out += item.name + '<br>';
         outd += item.value + '<br>';
         innerName.innerHTML = name_out;
         innerValue.innerHTML = outd;
   })
};

function sortByName() {
   xArr.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
   name_out();
}

function sortByValue() {
   xArr.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
   name_out();
}

function myFunction() {
   let element = document.getElementById('name_out');
   while (element.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
   }
}
```

CSS

```
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    
    html {
    font-size: 10px;
    /* background: rgb(32, 8, 122); */
    }
    
    .body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* color: #343E5C; */
    line-height: normal;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    justify-content: center;
    }

    .square {
    width: 25rem;
    /* background: url(../img/column.png) no-repeat center/cover; */
    box-shadow: 0rem 2rem 4rem rgba(18,18,18,0.4);
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.1rem 6rem 3.2rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    }

    .inp_t {
        margin: 1rem;
    }

    .inputs {
        margin: 2rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .buttons {
        margin: 2rem;
    }
    /**/
    .textcols {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .textcols-item {
        white-space: normal;    
        display: inline-block;
        width: 48%;
        vertical-align: top;
        
    }
    .textcols .textcols-item:first-child {
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
```

Comment: "у меня возникла проблема" - ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так у вас и указывается одна колонка

```
let element = document.getElementById('name_out');
```

В таком случае надо и вторую указать

```
function myFunction() {
   let element = document.getElementById('name_out');
   let element1 = document.getElementById('outd');
   while (element.firstChild && element1.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
      element1.removeChild(element1.firstChild);
   }
}
```

Если я правильно понял

и массив тогда очистить

```
xArr = [];
```